# Xamarin Visual Studio Compiles but always fails to deploy

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have recently installed Xamarin into my pre existing Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. I had installed my VS 2015 on Win 10 Home edition and after I upgraded to the Pro edition I installed Xamarin. The installation went without incident.

So I created a new Cross device solution in VS, it compiles [skips the IOS one bcos I'm on Windows] but it always fails to deploy.

In the logs I see the following errors:

1. During VS IDE initialization

Metadata lookup failed
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchProjectEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Assembly& assembly, ReferenceType refType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.VSTypeResolutionService.SearchEntries(AssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreTypeCase, Assembly& assembly)
   at

2. Whenever I try to deploy the solution

System.InvalidOperationException
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider.StartEmulator(IAndroidVirtualDevice virtualDevice, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\34a92cd0\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Devices\AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider.cs:line 137
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.StartUp(IMonoAndroidDevice device, IProgressReport progress, IAndroidVirtualDeviceProvider virtualDeviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\34a92cd0\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.cs:line 0
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.Execute(StartupVirtualDeviceCommand command, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\34a92cd0\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.cs:line 45
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.Execute(TCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3420\34a92cd0\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 125

Any and all help much appreciated.

Comment: Testing on a device or emulator??

Comment: It sounds like your Android emulator isn't starting. Can you start the emulator from Visual Studio (without deploying) and see if it boots up? Otherwise, try deploying to a physical Android device. If you're using the default Android emulators from VS, I've had some bad luck getting those working. GenyMotion and Xamarin's Android Player are good options.

Comment: Sorry for the delay ....had to re install the OS @sJy Its on the emulator

Comment: @user1628539 Try starting the emulator seperately & once it is loaded & unlocked, run the app. Also try in a physical device.